# Turn off default routes in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, routes, kohana, url-routing, kohana-3

I believe I know how to do this, but wanted to verify with my awesome community peeps. =)

Here's an example:

I have a Controller class called 'tami', with an action 'index'.

I know that if I want someone to access that controller/action combo via an URL other than "/tami/" or "/tami/index", then I should add a route, via something like this:

```
Route::set('pretty_tami', 'these-are-my-initials(/<action>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'tami',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

But, users can still access this page via `/tami/`.

#### How can I turn off the default routing, so that the only valid routes are the ones I define?

I assume I can just remove the default route found in `kohana/application/bootstrap.php`. Is that correct? Or would that break something else?

Comment: Dont afraid, every script in your APPPATH dir can be changed for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say exactly the same as @simshaun — either remove the default route (leaving other controllers unreachable) or check in the `before()` function in `Controller_Tami` for the uri to see if it's what you're after.

If you're using Kohana 3.1, [you can now use lambda logic/anonymous functions to define your routes](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic).

Something like this would take the extra routing logic out of the controller (which is good as we're keeping it in one place):

```
Route::set('default', function($uri)
    {
        if ($uri == 'tami' OR $uri == 'tami/index')
        {
            // Route not allowed by the default methods
            throw new Kohana_404_Exception("Route not permitted");
        }
    },
    '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))'
);
```

Something I haven't yet used but it looks amazingly powerful.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way would be to remove the default route in your bootstrap file, yes.  However, any controllers that you have not manually specified a route for can no longer be accessed.

What I would do is create a class, e.g. `Controller_Derouter` that Controller_Tami extends.  Use the `before()` method in Controller_Derouter to test if the controller was accessed from the default route, and if so, throw a 404.  I think you should be able to do that by comparing `$this->request->controller` against the first URI segment.

Edit: The solution mentioned above is unnecessary if you ever only plan on disabling the default route for just the Tami controller. If that's the case, you could just implement the before() method directly in the Tami controller.

Comment: So, apparently this isn't as common as I thought it might be. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Exactly what I'd say. Either remove the default one or check your routes in the controller logic.

Also, in KO3.1 [you can use lambda logic to define your routes](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic) which may prove useful for this. Writing an answer for this, but it's more complicated than this answer for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
Route::set('pretty_tami', 'these-are-my-initials/<action>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'tami',
    ));
```

So there wouldn't be a default `action`. And you probably want to update the `default` route (if you still have one) with a regex to exclude `tami`.

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('controller' => '/^(?!tami)/'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```